# Is recyclerview need scrollview?

Tags: xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I use recyclerview to showing the notification. But, I confuse, is recyclerview must be wrap in scrollview, so we can scroll it down? or we can scroll it even without scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need scroll view for recycler view, put the recycler view inside a constraint layout and link the recycler view from `top` and `bottom` and set it's height to `0dp` and link the recycler view only from `top` and set it's height to `wrap-content`